# PreferenceFragment is shown transparently

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences

I'm trying to show a `PreferenceFragment` after I select the Preferences option in my ActionBar.
However, after replacing current content with the `PreferenceFragment` you can see the old content below it. As in, you can see straight through the preferences.

Am I missing something here? I used an example from a book I own, which didn't use any layout files for the preferences. Do you need those?

**Used code:**

Actionbar menu

```
private boolean MenuChoice(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 0:
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ReaderPreferences prefs = new ReaderPreferences();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, prefs);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            return true;

        }
        return false;
    }
```

PreferenceReader

```
public class ReaderPreferences extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // --load the preferences from an XML file---
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference);
    }
  }
```

**Actual result:**

[image]

As you can see, you look straight through my preferences. 
What did I do wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem. Is there no solution to get it work with PreferenceFragments instead of PreferenceActivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually fixed it with a very easy fix.

I simply called the `PreferenceFragment` in a new `Intent`, and it worked perfectly.

For anyone with the same problem:

**Prefs.java**

```
public class ReaderPreferences extends PreferenceActivity {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // --load the preferences from an XML file---
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference);
        }
```

**In my main screen when pressing a button:**

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Prefs.class);
            startActivity(i);
```

That's all. After setting the preferences simply press the back button and you're done.

Comment: This solution works fine if your using PreferenceActivity, However, you cannot use this method with PreferenceFragment. You say you are calling PreferenceFragment through an Intent, but in your solution in Prefs.java you are using PreferenceActivity not PreferenceFragment.

Answer (score 8):

Create your **PreferenceFragment.java** class like this:

```
    public class UserPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        getView().setClickable(true);
    }

}
```

**the trick is:**

```
@Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            getView().setClickable(true);
        }
```

**EDIT:**

Edited as suggested by JDenais, even if it's not strictly necessary to the topic.

Comment: I suggest that you also add : getView().setClickable(true); to prevent clicks from going through the fragment and accidentally clicking the activity below.

Comment: In case of using PreferenceActivity for older APIs in spite of PreferenceFragment one should change `onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)` to `onResume()` and  `getView` to `getListView`.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and solved it //without having to start a new activity//. This method has the advantage that your main activity doesn't go through a pause-resume cycle. The key is to have your main UI as a fragment, and then hide it when the Pref fragment is called. The main fragment can be included statically or dynamically.

```
 FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 AppSettingsFragment prefs = new AppSettingsFragment();
 // This adds the newly created Preference fragment to my main layout, shown below
 ft.add(R.id.main_layout,prefs);
 // By hiding the main fragment, transparency isn't an issue
 ft.hide(mMyMainFragment);
 ft.addToBackStack(null);
 ft.commit();
```

The `main_layout.xml` looks like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<!-- Uncomment for static fragment inclusion -->
<!-- fragment android:name="com.legynd.ui.MyMainFragment"
    android:id="@+id/mainfragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" / -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 6):

The best and most portable solution is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970209/preferencefragment-background-color)

Which is:

> Adding the following code to your PreferenceFragment will
>   let you add a background color, image, etc.

```
@Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.your_color));

    return view; }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your ReaderPreferences implementation add:

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an empty layout for your activity like this:

**activity_settings.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

then in activity's onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    ReaderPreferences mReaderPreferences = new ReaderPreferences ();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
       .replace(R.id.settingsFragment, mReaderPreferences ).commit();
    }
```

Comment: This seems like a reasonable solution when you also include .addToBackStack(null) before commit();

Answer (score 1):

The background color can be set to the Fragment View in onStart().
As below:

```
public class ReaderPreferences extends PreferenceFragment {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
   super.onStart();
   View v = getView();
   v.setBackgroundColor(getActivity().getResources.getColor(R.color.my_color));
}
```

This works for me on all of my test devices.

The accepted answer is not the answer to what the question states here. In fact, its a workaround which creates a container activity for the preference fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your Fragment that extends PreferenceFragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck with the exact same issue, and after trying out a couple of things I found our that it was happening because in my case I had mixed up two different versions of Fragments and FragmentManagers.

The onCreate of my MainActivity looked like this:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new MainFragment())
                .commit();
```

However when I wanted to replace this MainFragment with my own PreferenceFragment, I tried using something similar to what you used:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, new SettingsFragment())
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
```

The way I understand it is that, you should use the same type of FragmentManager for replace to work, so I just had to go ahead and make appropriate changes to the way I wired up the MainFragment making it look like this:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new MainFragment())
            .commit();
```

Ofcourse, I had to refactor MainFragment to extend from `android.app.Fragment` instead of `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

Answer (score 0):

I tried Shayan_Aryan's solution, but my app was dying with error:

```
Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

So I had to create a LinearLayout with no text in the empty case.
Well I suppose there is a more elegant solution, but this was the only one that worked to me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

i used many techniques but no gain
Finally i fixed it by adding background of the container or the fragment layout like this

```
android:background="@android:color/white"
```

you just need to add in your Layout or the container view of you Fragment
Hope it will help